# RelativeLayout with ImageView on the right and 3 text views to the left of the image, one below another

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to use a RelativeLayout to display an image on the left side, and 3 text views, one below another, to the right of the image. Similar is explained here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html. The problem I'm having is that the 3rd text view does not display.

My code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="2dip">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="96dip"
        android:layout_height="96dip" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
        android:id="@+id/myIcon" android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/Line1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/myIcon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:text="Line 1" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/myIcon"
        android:layout_below="@id/Line1"
        android:text="Line 2" android:id="@+id/Line2" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/myIcon"
        android:layout_below="@id/Line2"
        android:id="@+id/Line3" android:text="Line 3" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It's probably something really simple or obvious that I'm either doing wrong or forgetting to do, but I could really use a fresh pair of eyes taking a glance at this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

to your Line1 TextView. I'm not sure if this will fix your issue, but it's something to try.

Also, in regard to the '+' sign for IDs: These are for your id declarations. So, in all of your elements, you would have something like this:

```
android:id="@+id/SomeId"
```

Which is what you have. However, you do not need them for reference purposes. So

```
android:layout_below="@id/SomeId"
```

would be correct. Think of the '+' as declaring an ID and for referencing it, you do not need it.

Also: Try placing some background colors behind your views to make sure they are showing up how you expect them to. That's a debug tip that I use constantly.